# Manually download a specific driver from Windows update servers and archive the installation files?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-update

Say I could not find appropriate drivers from an OEM, but somehow Windows Update had them. For whatever reason, it is not publicly available.

I want to archive this driver to be installed later. Potential uses could be (a) to install the driver on a computer that does not/can not have internet, or (b) to backup the drivers in case Windows update servers shutdown or no longer provides the driver, say 20 years in the future.

Is this possible and how would I do so?

Additionally, how would you download a driver from Windows update for different hardware than the that of the PC doing the download? Say download drivers for Window 11 on Windows 10, or download drivers for a device that is not currently physically installed into the downloading PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you can search for and download update packages here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ The easiest way to find a driver for a device is to search for the Hardware ID in device manager

more detailed instructions and an example available here: https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/microsoft-update-catalog/